# Lua/Splash: Link to next page is not being executed

Tags: lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to write a Lua script to go to the next page of the website: http://quotes.toscrape.com/js/page/1/

My script:

```
    function main(splash, args)
      assert(splash:go(args.url))
      assert(splash:wait(0.5))
      assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector(".next a[href]").click()'))
      splash:set_viewport_full()
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
        png = splash:png(),
        har = splash:har(),
      }
    end
```

I tried multiple CSS Selectors which all work in the browser. However the Lua script only returns the first page and doesn't open the next.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause?

Thank you and best regards
Tobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I just added wait statement for 1 second. Here the correct code:

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector(".next a[href]").click()'))
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```